# endfloat can't handle many floats with redefined \efloatseperator

Tags: floats, endfloat

I have a LaTeX-document with a large number of figures that I want to be displayed at the end of the document using the `endfloat` package.
Since I don't want a `\clearpage` after every one of them I redefined `\efloatseparator` as recommended in the documentation using

```
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{}
```

This works fine as long as there's just a few figures in the document.
With the number of figures in my document however I get a number of LaTeX-errors and the figures are displayed badly or not at all.

In this example, the nineteenth figure seems to be to much:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[figuresonly, nolists, nomarkers]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{one}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{two}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{three}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{four}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{five}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{six}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{seven}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{eight}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{nine}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{ten}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{eleven}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{twelve}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{thirteen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{fourteen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{fifteen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{sixteen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{seventeen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{eighteen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{10}{\fbox{}}
    \caption{nineteen}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The nineteenth figure is not displayed.
Adding another float makes a total mess of the first few figures.

Is LaTeX just not able to handle that many figures without `\clearpage` between them?

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage{morefloats}
```

works around the issue.